# Nginx: How can I rein in this rogue app from changing url to 'localhost'

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I go to this url http://**dev.local.org**:3002/ent/select#/engines  -  hosts file has entry 127.0.0.1 dev.local.org

[image]

This application sends it to http://**localhost**:3002/ent/select#/engines - I want the url to remain as http://dev.local.org:3002/ent/select#/engines.

What config should I change in my nginx to rein-in that rogue application?

```
    server {
      listen        3002 ;
      server_name   _;
      include   common.conf;
      #include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

      location / {
        set $backend http://appsearch:3002;
        proxy_pass $backend; # Use variable To avoid upstream host not found error.
        include common_location.conf;
      }
    }#server
```

[image]

Comment: `#/engines` is so-called *hash* part of an URI, it is set from your page JS and you can't control it from your server side. That URI part is not send to web server at all when a browser makes HTTP request.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, sorry "#engines" is not the problem, "localhost" is the problem. Edited that and highlighted.

Comment: Try `listen 3002 default_server; server_name dev.local.org;`. If it won't help, try additionally `proxy_set_header Host dev.local.org;`.